# Response code 400 when trying to set AWS ECS scale-in protection

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs

I want to to set scale-in protection as explained [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/task-scale-in-protection-endpoint.html) via a PUT request to `$ECS_AGENT_URI/task-protection/v1/state`.

However, I always get the following error: `Response code 400 (Bad Request)` .

This is my code:

```
const got = require("got");

const SCALE_IN_PROTECTION_DURATION_MINUTES = 15;
const TASK_PROTECTION_URI = `${process.env.ECS_AGENT_URI}/task-protection/v1/state`;
try {
  const minutes = SCALE_IN_PROTECTION_DURATION_MINUTES;
  await got(TASK_PROTECTION_URI, {
    method: "PUT",
    json: { ProtectionEnabled: true, ExpiresInMinutes: minutes },
  });
} catch (error) {
  logger.error(error);
}
```

`process.env.ECS_AGENT_URI` is set properly and the instance agent version is `1.70.0`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code was correct. The solution was to add the `ecs:UpdateTaskProtection`  permission to my ECS task as  described [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/userguide/task-scale-in-protection.html#task-scale-in-protection-iam).